# Posting Files Using cURL using PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

I am having problems posting files to an api I have built using cURL.

I can post small images (say 4KB) but when I try and attach a large image I get the following error:

Curl error: failed creating formpost data

The code I am using to make the cURL call is below:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");

try {  
    switch($type) {
        case "GET":
            break;
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            $fh = fopen('php://memory', 'rw'); 
            $data = http_build_query($vars, '', '&');
            fwrite($fh, $data);  
            rewind($fh);  
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh);  
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($data));  
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
            break;
        case "DELETE":
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
            break;  
        default:  
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Current verb is an invalid REST verb.'); 
    }
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {  
    curl_close($ch);  
    throw $e;  
} catch (Exception $e) {  
    curl_close($ch);  
    throw $e;
} 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Is there a cap on the file size for uploading an image through cURL.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: PHP's memory limit, 32bit system limiting you to 2gig files, open files limit, etc... there's lots of limits. Without more details, can't answer any better than that. What's in `$vars`?

Comment: $vars is the variables that I am posting so would look something like this:

$vars = array("name" => $name, "image" => "@/tmp/image.jpg");

Comment: Although I am not looking to upload 2GB files. This is happening with a file that is 148KB !

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into a limit thats set on the server.  Apache has the `LimitRequestBody` directive to allow the server admin to restrict upload sizes.  You can read more about it here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody

Server admins can apply Limits on Windows IIS services as well although only reliably from 6.0 onwards.

Comment: Many thanks for the pointer but I tried adding the following to my httpd.conf file and restarting apache and I am still unable to upload large files. <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/images"> LimitRequestBody 0 </Directory>

Comment: have you tried running curl manually from the command line to make sure that works? I used to do that to make sure the curl calls would work before I put it in PHP. That way you know if its a php problem only  docs are here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html